# JQuery AppendTo Function Not working in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, append

I have looked over my code, I can't find what is causing it to break in earlier versions of IE. The code works on FF, Chrome, and Safari.

The code is supposed to generate a div on the side in the reading list with a headline and photo, and then an x on the bottom to delete it. But, on IE, it shows only an x. 
Website: www.hearditfrom.com

I would really appreciate any help! Thanks in advance.

Here is the code:

```
  $(function() {
        $('a.addtoreadinglist').click(function(){
            $('<li id="arrayorder_' + $(this).attr('data-storyid') + '">   <div class="reading_list drop-shadow lifted"><div class="reading_list_container"><p class="reading_list_story"><a class="rlstory" href="' + $(this).attr('data-url') + '" data-storyid="' + $(this).attr('data-storyid') + '">' + $(this).attr('data-headline') + '</a></p></div><div class="rlbuttons"><a class="deletefromrl" data-storyid="'+ $(this).attr('data-storyid') + '" data-parent="arrayorder_' + $(this).attr('data-storyid') + '"><div class="deletebutton">x</div></div></div></li>').appendTo('#list ul');
            $(this).hide();
            $('#instruction').fadeOut('slow').remove();
            var order = $('#list ul').sortable("serialize") + '&update=update'; 
                $.post("updateReadingList.php", order, function(theResponse){
                     $("#response").html(theResponse);
                });                     
        })
    })


    //photo
    $(function() {
        $('a.addtoreadinglistphoto').click(function(){
            $('<li id="arrayorder_' + $(this).attr('data-storyid') + '"><div class="reading_list drop-shadow lifted"><div class="reading_list_container"><p class="reading_list_story"><img class="reading_list_thumbnail" src="http://images.hearditfrom.com/timthumb.php?src=' + $(this).attr('data-photoname') + '&q=100&w=30&h=30" /><a class="rlstory" href="' + $(this).attr('data-url') + '" data-storyid="' + $(this).attr('data-storyid') + '">' + $(this).attr('data-headline') + '</a></p></div><div class="rlbuttons"><a class="deletefromrl" data-storyid="'+ $(this).attr('data-storyid') + '" data-parent="arrayorder_' + $(this).attr('data-storyid') + '"><div class="deletebutton">x</div></div></div></li>').appendTo('#list ul');
            $(this).hide();
            $('#instruction').fadeOut('slow').remove();
            var order = $('#list ul').sortable("serialize") + '&update=update'; 
                $.post("updateReadingList.php", order, function(theResponse){
                    $("#response").html(theResponse);
                });             
        })
    })
```

Comment: Please define `earlier versions of IE`.

Comment: Works fine in 9 and 10 with me as long as compatibility mode is disabled (which you can force if you like). I see the problem in IE8 and below.

Comment: what do you think the problem could be?

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, but have you tried just using append: `$('#list ul').append($('...'));`

Comment: yup I had tried that earlier and it didn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what is causing the problem, but from debugging in Chrome vs. IE8 I see the following line is the problem (minus the appendTo statement).

```
$('<li id="arrayorder_' + $(this).attr('data-storyid') + '"><div class="reading_list drop-shadow lifted"><div class="reading_list_container"><p class="reading_list_story"><img class="reading_list_thumbnail" src="http://images.hearditfrom.com/timthumb.php?src=' + $(this).attr('data-photoname') + '&q=100&w=30&h=30" /><a class="rlstory" href="' + $(this).attr('data-url') + '" data-storyid="' + $(this).attr('data-storyid') + '">' + $(this).attr('data-headline') + '</a></p></div><div class="rlbuttons"><a class="deletefromrl" data-storyid="'+ $(this).attr('data-storyid') + '" data-parent="arrayorder_' + $(this).attr('data-storyid') + '"><div class="deletebutton">x</div></div></div></li>').appendTo('#list ul');
```

I don't understand enough of what this code is doing, or have the wherewithal to debug it all, but you should be able to break it up into smaller statements and then figure out which one is causing the error. For example:

```
var $li = $('<li />', { id: 'arrayorder_' + $(this).prop('data-storyid'));
var $div1 = $('<div />').addClass('reading_list drop-shadow lifted');
var $div2 = $('<div />').addClass('reading_list_container');
etc

//add elements one at a time to the DOM
```

By not making all your declarations as concatenated strings it will be much easier to identify the culprit in the code. Notice that I used a self closing tag for each new element. For the list item I used a set of parameters to add the id. For the divs I used addClass. This helps to separate your code and simplifies debugging.

Also, I would use `prop` rather than `attr` because you are in jQuery 1.8.3.

I would use `data` to access data elements. `$(this).data('storyid');`

Good luck.

Comment: Just took another peek and your second link `<a>` is missing a closing tag. I'd bet dollars to dimes this is a case of a typo/tag error in that mammoth declaration. Other browsers are detecting and correcting the error while < IE8 cannot. The solution is still the same though. Simplify the code and the error will probably 'fix itself.'